# Is there a way to use Horstmann format in VS Code C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, format

While configuring the C/C++ Formatter, I learned about the Horstmann format.

```
int main()
{   while (x == y)
    {   something();
        somethingelse();

        if (some_error)
            do_correct();
        else
            continue_as_usual();
    }

    finalthing();
}
```

It's a coding style that combines K&R and Allman, and it looks good, so I'm trying to use it as a taste in my personal projects.

However, since it's not a major style, VS Code doesn't seem to support it. I'd like to know if there is a way to achieve a similar effect using parameters or other elements of Clang_format_style.

Comment: [The documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs) should have information about formatting and styles, and how to create your own.